# getInitialProps does not work with async function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-props

I have file in this path `./pages/blog/[id]/[title].js` and here are the codes that I have written :

```js
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import fetch from 'isomorphic-unfetch';
import BASE_URL from '../../../BaseURL';


const BlogSinglePage = props => {
  console.log(props.post);//undefined
  console.log(props);//{}
 return (
   <div></div>
 );
};

BlogSinglePage.propTypes = {
  post: PropTypes.object
};

BlogSinglePage.getInitialProps = async ({ query }) => {
    const res = await fetch(`${BASE_URL}/api/post/${query.id}`);
    const post = await res.json();
    return { post };
};

export default BlogSinglePage;
```

my problem is when `getInitialProps`  is an `async` function , `BlogSinglePage` 's props is empty but whenever `getInitialProps`  is not an `async` function , everything works and props is not empty

I have followed the code in [Implement the Post Page](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/fetching-data-for-pages/fetching-data-for-pages) line by line but it's not working for me

Comment: Have you tried to `console.log` the response and the post variable in the async version of `getInitialProps`? What is the output?

Comment: Does the fetch request actually return something ? You can check in the Network tab of your browser inspector.

Comment: getInitialProps runs on server side , so it doesn't show anything on network tab 

@giuseppedeponte

Comment: the output in server is correct but in client is empty 

@PierreV.

Comment: @DavoodH.m If you have followed the instructions, it should work. Does you index page work with async?

Comment: I test that in `./pages/about.js` file. it also doesn't work @nithin

Comment: @DavoodHobabi What about ./pages/index.js ?

Comment: @nithin not working

Comment: @nithin the problem is not index or any other page , the problem is that async function is not working. I still get my props and it's working but only the part where there are sync elements

Comment: @DavoodHobabi I would suggest you go through this repl and see if you have followed the same steps. https://repl.it/repls/EverlastingDistantUpgrade. I have copied the same code and follow the same paths as mentioned in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea why this was the problem ,

but i reinstall next js with `next-cli` and the problem was solved :)